# How static variable in classes being allocated in memory?

Tags: c++, variables, static, allocation

```cpp
class car
{
public:
    static int i;
};

int car::i = 7;
int main ()
{   
    cout << car::i;
    return 0;    
}
```

Is a static variable allocating memory because of it's definition outside class and declaring it inside class just to become a member of class ? and why when it becomes constant we didn't define it outside class  ?

I understand that static variable being allocated in global and static variable segment in memory and static variable don't belong to any object .

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: _"and why when it becomes constant we didn't define it outside class"_ This is actually wrong. You still need to initialize the `static` members outside of the declaration (except for constant integral or enumeration type indeed).

Comment: it can be defined inside the class using `inline` since c++17

Comment: [The reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) should answer all of your questions ;)

Comment: @Fareanor  when it becomes constant we didn't need to define it outside . we can define it inside and this won't occur any error

Comment: @AbdoMostafa I'm afraid you're wrong. You can initialize it inside only for constant integral types (or enumerations). In your case it works because `int` ***is*** an integral type. If you don't believe me, just try by yourself with something else (for example `std::string`), you'll see, it will not work. But as @asmmo mentioned, you still can initialize them inside the class if declared `inline` (since C++17). Once again, read the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

> How static variable in classes being allocated in memory?

Static class variables have **static** storage.